# StructureMap | How to create a singleton instance / get always the same instance

Tags: c#, structuremap

I have a class `UserManagement` and always want to get the same `instance` (like singleton pattern). So my problem is now, that I always get a new `instance` insted of the named "Singleton". I'm new to `StructureMap`. I have tried both version (http://structuremap.github.io/object-lifecycle/) (http://structuremap.github.io/glossary/) described on the website.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Container container = new Container(new UserManagement());

        //UserManagement instance = container.GetInstance<UserManagement>("Singleton");
        UserManagement instance = container.GetInstance<UserManagement>();
        MessageBox.Show(instance.Test);
    }
}

public interface IUser
{
    void DoSomethingFancy();
}

public class User : IUser
{
    public void DoSomethingFancy()
    {

    }
}

public interface IDatabase
{
    void DoSomething();
}

public class Database : IDatabase
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {

    }
}

public class UserManagement : Registry
{
    public string Test;

    private Container _Container;
    private IUser _User;
    private IDatabase _Database;

    public UserManagement()
    {
        _Container = new Container(_ =>
        {
            _.For<IUser>().Use<User>();
            _.For<IDatabase>().Use<Database>();
        });

        _User = _Container.GetInstance<IUser>();
        _Database = _Container.GetInstance<IDatabase>();

        Test = DateTime.Now.ToString();

        //For<UserManagement>().AddInstances(x =>
        //{
        //    x.Type<UserManagement>().Named("Singleton");
        //});

        For<UserManagement>().Singleton();
    }
}
```

## Update

My solution has 3 projects

1. BootstrapperLibrary (**class library** - `Bootstrapper`)
2. Gui (**WpfApp** - `MainWindow.xaml`)
3. Framework (**class library** - `LoginAction` - `UserManagement`)

### BootstrapperLibrary

#### Bootstrapper.cs

```
public static class Bootstrapper
{
    public static Container Container => _Container ?? (_Container = InitializeContainer());
    private static Container _Container;

    public static Func<Container> InitializeContainer;    
}
```

### Gui

#### App.xaml.cs

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        Bootstrapper.InitializeContainer += InitializeContainer;
    }

    private Container InitializeContainer()
    {
        Container container = new Container(c => c.Scan(scanner =>
        {
            scanner.TheCallingAssembly();
            scanner.WithDefaultConventions();
            scanner.AssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory();
        }));
        container.Configure(c =>
            {
                c.ForSingletonOf<UserManagement>();
                c.For<IUser>().Use<UserAdv>();
            }
        );

        return container;
    }
}
```

#### MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Gui.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
        xmlns:myFramework="clr-namespace:MyFramework;assembly=MyFramework"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="383,228,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                    <myFramework:LoginAction/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Button>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

### Framework

#### LoginAction.cs

```
public class LoginAction : TriggerAction<DependencyObject>
{
    protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
    {
        UserManagement userManagement = Bootstrapper.Container.GetInstance<UserManagement>();
        Console.WriteLine(userManagement.Test); //Just to see if it's still the same instance who holds for example the current user.
    }
}
```

#### UserManagement.cs

```
public interface IUser
{
    string Name { get; }
    void DoSomethingFancy();
}

public class User : IUser
{
    public string Name { get; } = "default";

    public void DoSomethingFancy()
    {

    }
}

public class UserAdv : IUser
{
    public string Name { get; } = "Advanced";

    public void DoSomethingFancy()
    {

    }
}

public interface IDatabase
{
    void DoSomething();
}

public class Database : IDatabase
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {

    }
}

public class UserManagement
{
    public string Test;

    public IUser User;
    private IDatabase _Database;

    public UserManagement(IUser user, IDatabase database)
    {
        User = user;
        _Database = database;

        Test = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
}
```

If I understood correctly, my main application now initializes and configures the `Container` within the `application startup`. The `Bootstrapper` class is holding a static instance there. `MyFramework` fetches an instance of `UserManangement` from the static `Container` instance.

Is this the correct way how to use `StructureMap`? Thank you for your patience!

Comment: Your container should be created once, at the composition root of your application. Hold a reference to it, like in a static variable. You don't want to make a new one on every button click.

Comment: So *KBO*s solution whould be the right way how to use the structuremap in combination with `singleton`?

Comment: At a glance it looks ok now that it is edited. I have limited experience with Structuremap specifically, I just know how DI works and you are not supposed to keep creating new instances of your container.

Comment: My problem is, that I have a dll(1) with for example the `UserManagement` class, a second dll(2) where for example `IUser`, `IDatabase` is declared and my app with the `MainWindow`. So If I create a `Container` inside of the `App.cs` (In the `MainWindow` Application), how can I get a singleton Instance inside of the first (1) dll?

Comment: If you are trying to access things in dll2 from dll1, which is referenced by dll2, then I think you misunderstand DI. Any dependencies needed by dll1 should be injected by your IoC container.

Comment: No I just want to use a `singleton` instance of `UserManagement`. `UserManagement` is declared inside of dll1 and there I want to have a `singleton`. But I want to avoid the classic `singleton` pattern and use DI to have the ability of customer specific plugins etc. So I create my `IContainer` in the `MainApp` with all DIs. The only question is, how can I acces inside of dll1 a `singleton` instance of `UserManagement`.

Comment: Let StructureMap do its work. Inject a `UserManagement` object as a constructor argument to the consuming class. This will work, if that class is also created by StructureMap, i.e. if it is registered during bootstrapping. Another option is to use service location. This is sub-optimal from an architectural point-of-view (anti-pattern), but works... You can register StructureMap with the Microsoft `CommonServiceLocator`. Than you are independent from a specific DI framework. Add a `CommonServiceLocator` reference to the required DLLs and use the `ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance()` methods.

Comment: Could you please have one more look at my update? Thanks!

Comment: @Dominic: Have you tested it? From my point of view the singleton behaviour should work as expected. I recommend to place the bootstrapper in your EXE project and call the initialization directly on startup, not on the first container request. So you can see registration errors directly and can use constructor injection. To reduce/prevent code behind, I also recomment to use the popular MVVM design pattern for the app. Please see https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/getting-started-with-mvvm-light-with-wpf for details on DI, MVVM and the CommonServiceLocator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should declare:

```
ForConcreteType<UserManagement>().Singleton();
```

**Edit:**

You may implement a bootstrapper class and call the `Initialize()` method during program startup:

```
public sealed class Bootstrapper
{
  private static StructureMap.Container _container;

  public StructureMap.Container MyContainer
  {
    get { return _container; }
  }

  static Bootstrapper() 
  {
  }

  public static Initialize()
  {
    StructureMap.Configuration.DSL.Registry registry = new StructureMap.Configuration.DSL.Registry();

    registry.For<IUser>().Use<User>();
    registry.For<IDatabase>().Use<Database>();
    registry.ForConcreteType<UserManagement>().Singleton();

    _container = new Container(registry);
  }
}
```

Remove the container initialization from the `UserManagement` class and let the DI framework inject the concrete types/objects.

```
public class UserManagement
{
    public string Test;

    private IUser     _user;
    private IDatabase _database;

    public UserManagement(IUser user, IDatabase database)
    {
      _user     = user;
      _database = database;

      Test = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
}
```

Modify your WPF test window:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    static MainWindow()
    {
      // only for demonstration!!!
      Bootstrapper.Initialize();
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Container container = Bootstrapper.MyContainer;

        UserManagement instance = container.GetInstance<UserManagement>();
        MessageBox.Show(instance.Test);
    }
}
```